# Is this textbook wrong about scaling eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fehs9.png]

This doesn't seem right. The eigenvalue of $s\boldsymbol{v}$ should be $s \lambda$ right? Or no?

Comment: No.$ A(sv) = s(Av) = s(\lambda v) =\lambda(sv)$.

Comment: If you scale the *matrix* by $s$, then you do scale all of its eigenvalues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No: by linearity of matrix multiplication,
$$ A(sv) = sAv = s\lambda v = \lambda(sv), $$
so $sv$ still has eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you multiply $sv$ by $A$, you will get $sv\lambda$.

I see where you are coming from with the eigenvalue being $s\lambda$, but $sv\lambda$ is only $\lambda$ times $sv$, so the eigenvalue is still $\lambda$.